# Strange date format from output plan program

Tags: php, time, converters

In my database there is a column called begindate and it's the output from a different program. I need to convert it so I can print it on my website, but I don't know what kind of date format it is, and how to convert it.

here is a example: `'736874'` and `'736872'`

It's not Epoch because when I convert it it says it's `Friday, January 9, 1970` but it should be at least '2017'

So I have 2 assumptions.

- this is a data format that I just don't know of
- this is a string generated by that other program

(I don't know the name of the other program, but it's used for planning.)

Comment: If there's no way to contact the person who devised this odd date system then you need to hope there's someone here who's encountered this before. Odds of that happening are close to 0 since we've had and used standard date notations for many years now and this is not one of them.

Comment: @apokryfos I just contacted the people who worked with it. They say it are seconds or minutes from a specific date, it could be january first 1900. And now I have to calculate it te figure the date out and some system to print it on my website

Comment: Wow, they actually made it less clear on what it is

Comment: @apokryfos yeah wish me luck..

Comment: Good luck. Post an answer if you figure it out. It might help others in the same situation.

Comment: I suspect it **is** an epoch based format, just not the **Unix** epoch. If you don't know the exact date it represents it's going to be really hard to guess.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I figured it out. It is ...... days from january 1th 0001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This date format is called a serial date. It is mostly used in Excel.

How it works, it starts on January 0 1900. The serial date represents the number of days from that moment. So on 19 January the serial date is 36544.

Here is a link to full explanation http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

To change it to dd/mm/yyyy with php you can use the following code:
(https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/157341-convert-serial-date-into-ddmmyyyy/)

```
<?
    function convertSerialDate($date)   {
        $timestamp = ($date - 25569) * 86400;
        return date("d/m/Y",$timestamp);
    }

    print convertSerialDate(733535);
?>
```

Because this date is 6 numbers it is a little bit different. the date represents the days from `january 1th 0001`. 
so you need to use this number `719543`

`$timestamp = ($date - 719543) * 86400;`